# dynamic xml using php

Tags: php, xml

i have an xml file. how to make dynamic xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<jukebox>

    <song title="When the Levee Breaks" artist="Kansas Joe and Memphis Minnie" url="songs/levee.mp3" />
    <song title="Better Leave that Stuff Alone" artist="Will Shade" url="songs/alone.mp3" />
    <song title="Walk Right In" artist="Cannon's Jug Stompers" url="songs/walk.mp3" />


</jukebox>
```

here i have to fetch files from database. how it is possible?

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Can you give us more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite don't understand if you want to pull out those information from MySQL to XML or XML to HTML...

In the first case, we'll need more informations like :

- Your MySQL schema
- How do you extract info from there now
- What did you try so far

In the second case, you can use that code :

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<jukebox>

    <song title="When the Levee Breaks" artist="Kansas Joe and Memphis Minnie" url="songs/levee.mp3" />
    <song title="Better Leave that Stuff Alone" artist="Will Shade" url="songs/alone.mp3" />
    <song title="Walk Right In" artist="Cannon\'s Jug Stompers" url="songs/walk.mp3" />


</jukebox>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$songs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('song');
foreach($songs as $song){
    echo '<a href="'.$song->getAttribute('url').'">'.$song->getAttribute('title').' by '.$song->getAttribute('artist').'</a>';
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://codepad.org/VmrP1BjN)

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on a number of other factors you haven't elaborated on, however given you intend on generating the file with **PHP**, and you've sorted out your database logic, something like this would work:

```
<?php foreach($songs as $song): ?>

    <song title="<?php echo $song['title']; ?>"
        artist="<?php echo $song['artist']; ?>"
        url="<?php echo $song['url']; ?>" />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

More details are really necessary to give you any more of answer though. For example, language?